# build.gradle in the project vs. build.gradle in the app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I started a project in Android Studio, with IntelliJ.

The project includes two files called `build.gradle`. One is under the folder `app`, and one is under the main folder which is my project name, say `MyProject`.

Why the need for two? What is the difference between the two `build.gradle`s?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295933/difference-between-build-gradleproject-and-build-gradlemodule

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio project consists of modules, libraries, manifest files and Gradle build files.

Each project contains one **top-level** Gradle build file.
This file is named *build.gradle* and can be found in the top level directory.

This file usually contains common config for all modules, common functions..

Example:

```
  //gradle-plugin for android
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()  //or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'        
    }
  }

  // common variables
  ext {
     compileSdkVersion = 19
     buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"
  }

  // a custom function
  def isReleaseBuild() {
     return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
  }

  //common config for all projects
  allprojects {
     version = VERSION_NAME

     repositories {
       mavenCentral()
     }
  }
```

**All modules have a specific `build.gradle` file**. 
This file contains all info about **this** module (because a project can contain more modules), as config,build tyoes, info for signing your apk, dependencies....

Example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    //These lines use the constants declared in top file
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME  //it uses a property declared in gradle.properties
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE) 
    }

    // Info about signing
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    // Info about your build types
    buildTypes {
        if (isReleaseBuild()) {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
    }

    // lint configuration
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

//Declare your dependencies  
dependencies {
    //Local library
    compile project(':Mylibrary')
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    // Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'

}
```

You can find more info here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. I've never made a project with multiple modules. In the case that there is only one module, does it matter which build.gradle file I use for, say, a dependency?

Comment: @Suragch dependencies are always in the module

Comment: What about the `dependencies { classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'  }` section in the top-level build.gradle in your first example?

Comment: Perhaps add to your answer what format the Gradle build file is in? A [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to it and it works well when you use it in such a way

```
import 'package:webapp/layout.dart';

const int largeScreenSize = 1366;
const int mediumScreenSize = 768;
const int smallScreenSize = 360;
const int customScreenSize = 1100;

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.largeScreen,
    this.mediumScreen,
    this.smallScreen,}) : super(key: key);

  static bool isSmallScreen(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < smallScreenSize;

  static bool isMediumScreen(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= mediumScreenSize &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < largeScreenSize;

  static bool isLargeScreen(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= largeScreenSize;

  static bool isCustomScreen(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= mediumScreenSize &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= customScreenSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints){
        double _width = constraints.maxWidth;
        if(_width >= largeScreenSize){
          return largeScreen;
        }
        else if(_width < largeScreenSize && _width >= mediumScreenSize){
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;
        }
        else {
          return smallScreen ?? largeScreen;
        }
      }

    );
  }
}
```