# Difference between build.gradle (Project) and build.gradle (Module)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to add a dependency of Android Asynchronous Http Client into my project. So there are two *build.gradle* files in the project.

[image]

As per my understanding, there are different kind of dependencies:

1. One which defined on the root level of *build.gradle* (Project:My-app)
2. One inside the buildscript of the *build.gradle* (Project:My-app)
3. Another is build.gradle (Modules:app)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies) is about repositories for dependencies of the buildScript, explain a bit about first two types.

Also build.gradle (Project:My-app) says

```html
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

So I guess the dependency code of Android Asynchronous Http Client should be added in *build.gradle* (Module:app).

How does it all fit together?

Comment: if external library, yes you should add at  `build.gradle(Modules:app)` or go to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> (Choose project you want to add library) -> Dependencies` where you will see a green cross sign, by tapping that choose `Module Dependency` and add yout library automatically

Comment: Adding to build.gradle(Module:app), giving me an error that `Failed to find: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5`  why it is not able to download directly, i have also set the proxy. I downloaded the jar file, and tried manually but as `File Repository` ..is it the correct way.

Comment: for simplicity use `Project Structure` go to `Modules` and choose your project. There you will see a `green cross sign`. Clicking that will open `New Module` window. There you choose to import your library.If you have `.jar` file then below choose `import .JAR or .AAR package`.
Otherwise copy your jar to `libs` folder and on your `Module:app` add these dependencies:
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/your_jar_file.jar')
}`

Comment: This is a good reading https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

*build.gradle* (Project:My-app)

> Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to
> all sub-projects/modules.

Each project contains a *top-level Gradle file*. It usually contains *common configurations* for all `modules`. Whatever is included in this top-level Gradle file, it will affect all *modules*.

Example:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        //Maven plugin
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

build.gradle (Module:app)

> Build file of your specific module *(where you add your dependencies, signing configurations, build types, flavors, etc.)*

All *modules* have a specific Gradle file. Whatever is included in this *gradle* file, it will only affect the *module* that is included on.

Example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hrskrs.gesturefun"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':gesture-fun')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 82):

It's a bit confusing because Android Studio by default shows both `build.gradle` files right next to each other (when using the Android view).

[image]

If you switch to the Project view you can see the actual structure and where the different `build.gradle` files are located.

[image]

The `build.gradle` (Project: MyApplication) file is in the root folder of the project and its configuration settings apply to every module in the project. A module is an isolated piece of the bigger project. In a multi-module project, these modules have their own jobs but work together to form the whole project. Most Android projects only have one module, the app module.

The `build.gradle` (Module: app) file here is in the `app` folder. Its build settings apply only to the app module. If there were another module, then that module would have its own `build.gradle` file, too. As an [example](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library), I made a library project with three modules: a library module, a demo app module, and another app module that I plan to use for testing. Each of them have their own `build.gradle` files that I can tweak.

[image]

In a basic project, almost everything you need to edit will be in the app module's `build.gradle` file. You can remember it like this:

> **You're making an *app*, so go to the `build.gradle` (Module: *app*) file.**

## Further reading

- [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) (Android documentation--very readable and useful)
- [Introduction to multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html) (Gradle documentation)

Comment: This answer it much better as it explains what are Projects and Modules.

Comment: Very well written!

Answer (score 5):

About the relation of the two `gradle` files, **hrskrs** made a very clear explanation，and I will make some supplement about it.

If your project only has one Module (such as **app**), the advantage of the top **build.gradle (Project:My-app)** not show very clear. Because you can configure everything in **build.gradle (Module:app)** about the Module, and only modify one file when upgrading in the following days.

But if your project has five modules, and it happened that they have a same dependence **A**, if you don’t use the top **build.gradle (Project: My-app)** you need to maintain five files in the following days.

By the way, the **build.gradle (Module:app)** can overwrite the  **build.gradle (Project:My-app)**.

This design can improve the maintainability of the app.

Comment: What do you mean by 1) *"not show very clear"* (seems incomprehensible) and 2) *"in the following days"* (why would time matter? )? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49445648/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

[[Project vs Module]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67763434/4770877)

Projects' *build.gradle* file is used for common/shared logic. For example, you can define repositories here ([Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), Google, [JCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcenter/info), and custom) or specify `ext {}` with shared variables or `classpath`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63768305/4770877).

Module's `build.gradle` is used for the current module, like dependencies, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269079/4770877), ProGuard settings[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285427/4770877). Usually as a developer you should take care of this file.

Comment: Can you be specific than "Maven" and "Google"? For example, isn't the former "Maven Central" (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 0):

Things get more clear when you have multi-project module, then differences of module vs project Gradle are more clear.

You can use **project Gradle for defining required classpaths, plugins, source repositories (google, maven etc)** to fetch dependencies from. Changes in build.gradle of project level are applicable to complete project.
However there is a google issue tracker saying about dependency leak into project.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8301

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4741

But on a high level add something to the project level Gradle file if you want changes applicable to your complete project, this reduces maintaining dependency across modules.

While in **module level Gradle top-level module mainly used for signing info, version details, build types, product flavours, plugins and dependencies etc**.
Further lower-level modules mostly are concerned with the dependencies and plugins needed wrt that particular module, in general we just use **lower modules's build gradle for adding specific dependencies.**