# firebase android user database Sign up Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, genymotion

I was doing this tutorial on Android and Firebase but for some reason when I try to register a new driver it doesn't interact with Firebase at all. Though it does show it's connected to Firebase:

[image: Communication btwn the App & Firebase]

I have downgraded my API to 26 because of this error:

> Google Play services out of date. Requires 9256000 but found 9080470.

So I installed Genymotion to solve this issue as advised by contributors on this platform.

But it still doesn't communicate with Firebase. It returns 0 Errors and yet doesn't work.

I've installed GenyMotion but every time I try to run on it's devices it keeps crashing.

```
public class DriverLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "Test";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user!=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DriverLoginActivity.this, 
    MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);


        mLogin = findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegistration = findViewById(R.id.registration);

        mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
    password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new 
    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this, "sign up 
    error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Here are my build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ke.co.wafalmelogistics.wafalme"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And here is the Error I keep getting when I try to run the app on GenyMotion;

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: ke.co.wafalmelogistics.wafalme, PID: 1640
>                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdf)' on a null object reference
>                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
>                       at ke.co.wafalmelogistics.wafalme.DriverLoginActivity$2.onClick(DriverLoginActivity.java:61)
>                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> ```

ItI am a learner, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error points to: `at ke.co.wafalmelogistics.wafalme.DriverLoginActivity$2.onClick(DriverLoginActivity.java:61)` - this means that the error occurs on your `DriverLoginActivity` at line number 61. Which line is this?

Comment: @Grimthorr: mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

Comment: The error relates to `mAuth` not being initialised (is `null`), which is strange because you have already called `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`, and this cannot be `null`. Can you share your [`build.gradle` files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28295933/2754146) by editing them into the question please?

Comment: Delete this line from the dependencies block: `implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`.  It's a plugin and you are correctly applying it at the bottom of the file.  It doesn't belong in the dependencies.

Comment: Have u found a solution for this ?

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 3):

I get the same error because I was use Emulator ..
but when I try it in a real device it is working perfectly ..
Hope it works for you too..

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me using these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //NOT DEFAULT BELOW
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
}
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I use `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'`

change to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'`
`

Try this dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue in my project while running in the emulator but I solved this by using this in **Android Studio 3.0.1**

**app/build.gradle**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"
```

**build.gradle ( root directory )**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

there setting work for me

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1104. I think this is an acknowledged issue in the SDK that would be resolved in the next 1 or 2 SDK updates. A github user called Samstern posts this -

> A fix for this bug has been submitted internally, so this should be
>   fixed in the next 1-2 Firebase Auth SDK releases depending on the
>   release cycle.
>
> I am going to close this issue here since there's nothing more
>   FIrebaseUI can do, thanks for everyone who reported it!

Nonetheless, try the following and see if it works. To repeat what Bob Snyder said - Delete this line from the dependencies block: implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'. Upgrade your firebase to 11.8.0. So your app's build.gradle should look like something like this.

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
> ```

Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading Google Play Services in the emulator. It was not necessary to change anything in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For me works change from compile:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0
```

to compile:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0
```