# I cannot solve my build gradle file error

Tags: android, android-studio

My build gradle file give error from first day that I set up android studio and now I cant write standard build.gradle file . . Plese help me .
Please tell me that build.gradle file has a standard mode or each app has special build.gradle file ?

Comment: If you're new, then it's important to understand the difference between build.gradle(Project) and build.gradle(Module), see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295933/difference-between-build-gradleproject-and-build-gradlemodule

Comment: What is the question and what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each app should have about 2 build gradle files (as commented by Michael) and the standard thing about each of them is the structure of the Android-related configurations and plugins (as the link shared by Micheal shows ). So each app will have build files with special configuration values (specific to that app).