# Android project missing jetpack compose components

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to amdroid development. I'm trying to learn jetpack compose using official documentation and compose material catalog app by google. However, in their, I can see material 3 has bottomsheetscaffold, modalBottomsheet, and other components like vertical and horizontal pagers. However, when i create a new project in android Studio, I can't find those components. I can only use surface, scaffold, text, and some other basic components.

I've tried updating the android Studio, but nothing works.
How can I get all the missing components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies you wish to use in your [app build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39231028/5513788).

In this case, add the [Material 3 dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#dependency):

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1"
```

Add it in the
`dependencies {}` section.