# what is a "build.gradle.in" file?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to load an opencv example into Android Studio.

When I clone the repository, one of the files is ["build.gradle.in"](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/android_sdk/build.gradle.in).

Android studio normally uses "build.gradle" files, without the ".in" extension. (See
[build.gradle in the project vs. build.gradle in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880174/build-gradle-in-the-project-vs-build-gradle-in-the-app)
"android camera calibration"
https://github.com/rpng/android-camera-calibration/blob/master/app/build.gradle
etc.
).

What is a "build.gradle.in" file?
Do I need to do something with it?
Do I need to tell Android Studio to do something with it, and if so, how?

(I tried to search for "build.gradle.in" in my favorite search engine, but I get a bunch of irrelevant documents talking about placing the file "build.gradle" "in" some folder or another).

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: This is only a partial answer as I cannot tell what to do with that file)

From the contents of the repository (in particular [android_gradle_projects.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/79310a0051ed01b40fc0fc2fd7108c9bb2836de7/cmake/android/android_gradle_projects.cmake#L35)) it appears to be a template file used as input (therefore `.in`) to create a final `build.gradle` with dynamic content.

See e.g. line 35 of `android_gradle_projects.cmake`:

```
configure_file("${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/samples/android/build.gradle.in" "${ANDROID_BUILD_BASE_DIR}/build.gradle" @ONLY)
```

In combination with e.g. line 100 of [`build.gradle.in`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/android_sdk/build.gradle.in#L100):

```
minSdkVersion @ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION@
```

[configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) copies a file with modifications, e.g. replacing variables in the form of `@VAR@`.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't manage to figure out how to use the build.gradle.in file, but you can download the openCV android sdk, which will contain the same sample projects already configured for gradle.